# how to mock python postgres database

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, unit-testing, mocking

I try to mock my db but when I test it the result is None.

```py
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(
                    host="yhvh",
                    database="python_db",
                    user="postgres",
                    password="pass",
                    )
except:
    print("Unable to connect database")

# Open a cursor to perform database operation
cur = con.cursor()

def read(con):
    """
    Read data in Database
    """
    print("Read")

    # execute the query
    data ="SELECT id, name FROM employees"
    cur.execute(
        data
    )
    # fetchall - returns all entries
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for r in rows:
        print(f"id {r[0]} name {r[1]}")
```

this is the code for my testing

```py
    def test_read(self):

        expected = [9, 'aaa']

        with patch('psycopg2.connect') as mock_connect:
            mock_con_cm = mock_connect.return_value
            mock_con = mock_con_cm.__enter__.return_value
            mock_cur = mock_con.cursor.return_value
            mock_cur.fetchall.return_value = expected

            result = db.read(mock_connect)
            self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

I get an assertionError: [9, 'aaa'] != None

How the result to have a value that would result is equal to expected ?

Answer (score -1):

First you need to return the `rows` which contains the list of data from `read` function if not it will return `None`.
Then use `assertListEqual(expected, result)` to check the elements in the list.

Your final code will look like this.

```
def read(con):
    """
    Read data in Database
    """
    print("Read")

    # execute the query
    data ="SELECT id, name FROM employees"
    cur.execute(
        data
    )
    # fetchall - returns all entries
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for r in rows:
        print(f"id {r[0]} name {r[1]}")

    return rows
```

And assertion should be,

```
self.assertListEqual(expected, result)
```